# harmonic polynomials of order 3 in two dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

**Find all harmonic polynomials of order 3 in two dimensions.**

$p(x,y)= a+ bx+cy+dxy+ex^2y+fxy^2+gx^3+hy^3+i*x^2+j*y^2$

$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}= b+dy+2exy+fy^2+3gx^2+2*ix$

$ \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x \partial x}= 2ey+6gx+2*i$

$\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial y \partial y}= 2fx+6hy+2*j$

$0=\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x \partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial y \partial y}= 2fx+6hy+2ey+6gx+ 2*i + 2*j \Rightarrow 0=fx+3hy+ey+3gx+i+j$

$\iff 0=i+j, 0=f+3g, 0=3h+e $

So i get: $p(x,y)= a+bx+cy+dxy-3hx^2y-3gxy^2+gx^3+hy^3+ix^2-iy^2)$

I think, i don´t solve the question of the exercise correctly. Can i give more precious polynomials? Or what I should do on this exercise?

Comment: your $p$ should include an $x^2$ and a $y^2$ term as well

Comment: At the end of your last formula, it is a $-iy^2$ instead of $-jy^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the question on a different viewpoint.

Let us write your expression as a sum of homogeneous polynomials with resp. degree $0,1,2,3: $

$$p(x)= a+ (bx+cy)+(dxy+\alpha x^2+\beta y^2)+(ex^2y+fxy^2+gx^3+hy^3)$$

(I have added the omitted terms as signaled by  @Will Nagy). Let us consider the 3rd degree part.

You may know that harmonic functions can always be considered either as the real part, or as the imaginary part of a holomorphic function (due to Cauchy-Riemann equations). The 3rd degree polynomial functions are not that numerous: you have to turn to the real and imaginary parts of

$$\tag{1} z^3=k(x+iy)^3=k(x^3-3xy^2)+i k(3x^2y-y^3)$$

(where $k$ is any *real* constant). You recognize here the coefficients "-3" of your own computation.

To the real or the imaginary part of $(2)$, you must add (with the same "recipe") a degree 2 harmonic function, etc.

Comment: I know for a holomorphic function are real and imaginary part harmonic functions.  I see that $Re(z^3)=x^3-3xy^2, Im(z^3)=3x^2y-y^3$ are harmonic, but i don´t get what that has to do with my problem. I  complemented my above question with the omitted terms and calculate it again.

Comment: It has to do that in your solution you find  $\cdots  g.(x^3-3xy^2)+h.(-3x^2y+y^3)+\cdots$, not by mere chance...

Comment: ...(ctd) Doing this (taking the general linear combination of these two "privilegized" harmonic polynomials of degree 3) can be repeated for degree 2: $z^2=(x+iy)^2=(x^2-y^2)+i (2xy)$ gives the special function $x^2-y^2$ and $xy$ or $2xy$: and you find back, in your formula $i(x^2-y^2)+d(xy)$, a linear combination of them. etc.

Comment: I see..then the harmonic polynomials of order 3 in 2 dimensions have  as base: $x^2-y^2, xy, (y^3-3yx^2),(x^3-3xy^2),x,y,$ so i have dimension 6? Is this true?                                                                                                                But i don´t know why this hold, I found this: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.8731&rep=rep1&type=pdf So i´ll read it.

Comment: I have had a look this document. It is completely pertinent to the study with its fourth paragraph devoted to the "complex" method. But the writer of this study is writing in not reliable. For example in the first page, the set $B_2$ has 4 elements $\{x^2,y^2,xy,yx\}$ instead of 3: $\{x^2,y^2,xy\}$ !!! Besides, saying that "the discovery was made be xxx" (one of his/her friend ?) is ridiculous: it has been found around 1800).

Comment: Thanks, I´ll be careful at reading. Why we don´t take $x^2$ and $y^2$ together $ x^2-y^2 $ like in the case of order 3, there we also take $x^3-3xy^2$ and $-3x^2y+y^3$ as base and don´t split the two items in another two?And w is with the dimension of the harmonic polynomials of order 3 in 2 dimensions, which i ask?

Comment: $x^2$ isn't harmonic. Neither $y^2$

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn´t be a element of a base of the vector space of the harmonic polynomials in the vector space ?$x^2$ is not harmonic, but a base elemenet?

Comment: Impossible... a base element of the vector space of harmonic functions necessarily shares with others the property to be harmonic...

Comment: A reflexion about the non reliability of the document you have found: it has a single reference which is not even a thorough reference. This is never the case for real university papers.

Comment: A last point, don't forget $1, x, y$ in your basis elements... (real and imaginary parts of $z^0$ and $z^1.$)